# connection between android and php mysql give back null and empty

Tags: php, android, android-asynctask

i have this code that create connection between android and php using Asynctask  and json to get back the response but the problem is that the response is always empty or null

i know what is the problem it is : 
the **String TAG_NAME**   witch is the JSON nodethat must be the same in the php file.

this string always give "username" and do not take the user input.

so to fix this error??
anyone can help me ? i will appreciate that.

## AndroidPHPConnectionDemo

package pack.coderzheaven;

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
        Button b;
        EditText et, pass;

        TextView tv;
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

        private static String pid;
        private static String Username; 
        private static String Password;

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single person url
        // ******************************************************************
        // the localhost in the google android emulator = 10.0.2.2
        // the localhost in the genymotion emulator = 10.0.3.2
        // ******************************************************************
        private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
        // private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static  String TAG_NAME = "Username";
        private static  String TAG_pass = "password";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);



            pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Getting complete person details in background thread
                    new CheckLogin().execute();

                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
         * */
        class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            JSONArray productObj;

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting person details in background thread
             * */

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                // updating UI from Background Thread

                // Check for success tag

                // Username = et.getText().toString();
                // Log.e("username in create method", " the username is  " +
                // Username);
                int success;
                try {
                    // Building Parameters
                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));

                    // getting person details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that person details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login,
                            "GET", params);

                    // Log.e("JsonObject", json.toString());
                    // check your log for json response
                    // Log.d("Single person Details", json.toString());

                    // json success tag
                    success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received person details
                        productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

    //                  TAG_NAME = et.getText().toString();
        //               Log.e("username in create method", " the username is  " + TAG_NAME);
                    }

                    else {
                        // product with pid not found
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return null;
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
                if (productObj != null) {
                    try {
                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        et.setText(person.getString(Username));

                        //TAG_NAME = Username;

                        pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                et.getText().toString() + pass.getText().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                Log.e("after the post execute", " THE USERNAME IS  " + Username);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this and observe the veriations in your code and let me now what happened.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
    import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
    import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
    import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
    import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
    import org.json.JSONArray;
    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.ProgressDialog;
    import android.os.AsyncTask;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class AndroidPHPConnectionDemo extends Activity {
        Button b;
        EditText et, pass;

        TextView tv;
        HttpPost httppost;
        StringBuffer buffer;
        HttpResponse response;
        HttpClient httpclient;
        List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs;

        private static String pid;
        private static String Username; 
        private static String Password;

        // Progress Dialog
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;

        // JSON parser class
        JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();

        // single person url
        // ******************************************************************
        // the localhost in the google android emulator = 10.0.2.2
        // the localhost in the genymotion emulator = 10.0.3.2
        // ******************************************************************
        private static final String url_check_login = "http://10.0.3.2/check.php";

        // JSON Node names
        private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";
        private static final String TAG_PERSON = "person";
        // private static final String TAG_PID = "pid";
        private static  String TAG_NAME = "Username";
        private static  String TAG_pass = "password";

        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);



            b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Button01);
            et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);



            pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
            tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv);

            b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {

                    // Getting complete person details in background thread
                    new CheckLogin().execute();

                }
            });
        }

        /**
         * Background Async Task to Get complete person details
         * */
        class CheckLogin extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

            JSONArray productObj;

            /**
             * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
             * */
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AndroidPHPConnectionDemo.this);
                pDialog.setMessage("Loading person details. Please wait...");
                pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            /**
             * Getting person details in background thread
             * */

            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {

                // updating UI from Background Thread

                // Check for success tag

                // Username = et.getText().toString();
                // Log.e("username in create method", " the username is  " +
                // Username);



                    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                    params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", Username));

                    // getting person details by making HTTP request
                    // Note that person details url will use GET request
                    JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_check_login,
                            "GET", params);

                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return json.toString();
            }

            /**
             * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
             * **/
            protected void onPostExecute(String json) {
                // dismiss the dialog once got all details
int success;
success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);
                    if (success == 1) {
                        // successfully received person details

                        productObj = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PERSON); // JSON Array

    //                  TAG_NAME = et.getText().toString();
        //               Log.e("username in create method", " the username is  " + TAG_NAME);
                    }
                if (productObj != null) {
                    try {
                        // get first product object from JSON Array
                        JSONObject person = productObj.getJSONObject(0);

                        et.setText(person.getString(Username));

                        //TAG_NAME = Username;

                        pass.setText(person.getString(TAG_pass));

                        Toast.makeText(
                                getBaseContext(),
                                et.getText().toString() + pass.getText().toString(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                        Log.e("success in login", "SUCCESS IN LOGIN");

                    } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                Log.e("after the post execute", " THE USERNAME IS  " + Username);

                pDialog.dismiss();
            }
        }

}
```